# Storing JSON Array of Arrays in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the JSON in the following format stored in Postgres JsonB Column:

```
[
    [

            {"cid":"CID1","Display":"User One","FName":"User","LName":"One"},
            {"cid":"CID1","Display":"User Two","FName":"User","LName":"Two"},
            {"cid":"CID1","Display":"User Three","FName":"User","LName":"Three"},
            {"cid":"CID2","Display":"User One","FName":"User","LName":"One"},
            {"cid":"CID2","Display":"User Two","FName":"User","LName":"Two"},
            {"cid":"CID2","Display":"User Three","FName":"User","LName":"Three"}    

    ],


    [

            {"cid":"CID1","Display":"User One","FName":"User","LName":"One"},
            {"cid":"CID1","Display":"User Two","FName":"User","LName":"Two"},
            {"cid":"CID1","Display":"User Three","FName":"User","LName":"Three"},
            {"cid":"CID2","Display":"User One","FName":"User","LName":"One"},
            {"cid":"CID2","Display":"User Two","FName":"User","LName":"Two"},
            {"cid":"CID2","Display":"User Three","FName":"User","LName":"Three"}    

    ]
]
```

I want to take the first array by index and then query on Keys like cid, Display, FName, LName. Then in another query I would like to take the second array by index and query on the same keys. The query should return the rows that satisfy the query. What is the best possible format in which I can save such JSON and how can I query on keys as explained above?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: BTW, this json text is not well-formed.

Comment: You are right. There was a comma missing after the third element of the 2nd array. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Just a question, why are you declaring this field as jsonb instead of json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First statement returns two rows, one for each array.

```
    select jsonb_array_elements(msg->'root') as el
    from js
```

Then returns each individual values as text.

```
with aa as
(
    select jsonb_array_elements(msg->'root') as el
    from js
)
select jsonb_array_elements(el)->>'cid' as cid,
       jsonb_array_elements(el)->>'Display' as Display,
       jsonb_array_elements(el)->>'FName' as FName,
       jsonb_array_elements(el)->>'LName' as LName         
from aa;
```

This returns 3rd element of 2nd array

```
select (ARRAY(select * from jsonb_array_elements(A1.Elements)))[3] Elem
from
    (select (ARRAY(select * from jsonb_array_elements(msg->'root')))[2] Elements
    from js) A1;
```

Below value is according data I've used in my resxtester project. Maybe does not match with your json text.

> {"cid": "CID2", "FName": "User", "LName": "Three", "Display": "User
>   Three"}

Check it here: http://rextester.com/IAU74251

**Update**

Filter by some of the field of the first array:

```
select * from                
(select jsonb_array_elements(msg->'root'->0) as a from js) elem
where elem.a->>'Display' like '%Two';
```

Comment: Hi McNets, you are almost there. You have retrieved rows from both the arrays , however, I want to retrieve rows from only one array at a given point of time and not both. My query would contain the index, and that index would me tell which Array I need to work on. Somehow I need to retrieve particular Array given that index

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it. Now you can use index. @puneet

Comment: You are the savior, @McNets. Thank You.

Comment: Hey, being an absolute novice in PostgreSQL, I am hitting roadblocks very often. I want to construct a query to filter on "Display" Column, of 2nd Array , and return all json objects from 2nd Array satisfying the situation. Can you help me out?